# js passing function name as argument behaving differently with and withour parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have made a wrapper function for $.ajax, i pass url,type,data and success function name as argument to it when i need ajax request

```
   function postdata(url, type, data, succ)
    {
    console.log(succ);  
    //alert(succ);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            success: succ

        });

        return false;
    }
```

now 4rth argument is success function's name but behaving differently, one time it is working with name+parenthesis only, not working without parenthesis  example

```
      del = function(data) {
            alert("executed");


            $(":checked").each(function() {
                $(this).parent("li").slideUp();


            });

            $('#myModal').modal('hide');

        };

        postdata("delete/", "POST",gl_obj,del());
```

and other time it is working only name without parenthesis, example

```
      temp = function(obj) {

            obj = eval("(" + obj + ")");
            document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML += "<ul>";
            for (i in obj)
            {
                //document.write(obj[i].name+"<br/>");
                document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML += "<li data-id='" + obj[i].id + "' class='mylist'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbx'>" + obj[i].name + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove to-close'></span></li>";

            }
            document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML += "</ul>";

        };
        postdata("get_names/", 'GET', "", temp);
```

so "die" doesnt works , "diw()" woks and executes the die function, in contrast to it "temp" works fine withour parenthesis, can any one clear this confusion why it is behaving differently? and whats the concept

Comment: Your second example is trying to eval the returned data from the Ajax call... That is generally a really bad thing to do and could cause any number of problems (unrelated to your original question). What do you want to actually do on your page? (eval is evil should be your motto) :)

Comment: yes i know its bad habbit to write eval, but the other problem has snatched my concentration right now
actually a json object returns and temp gets it and on success adds template while die par deletes it and closes the model sildes up the deleted row..

Comment: Your main problem is that your `postdata` function only uses the callback *if the ajax call succeeds*. See testing example added below.

Comment: Please try the final version below. It will alert you of any error from the ajax call, so that we can find the actual cause of the problem. Please post the results. *Please also get rid of all the unneeded comments below* :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the actual problem was of dataType being passed wrong for del callbackfuncion se i modified the potion of code

```
function postdata(url, type, data, succ,dataType)
   {
console.log(succ);  
//alert(succ);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        dataType: dataType,
        data: data,
        success: succ

    });

    return false;
}
```

Now this will be based as blank in case of del and json in case of temp
for del:

```
postdata("delete/", "POST",gl_obj,del,"");
```

and for temp

```
 postdata("get_names/", 'GET', "", temp,"json");
```

Answer (score 3):

This is really rather obvious when you look at what the parenthesis does.

`functionname` is a function, just sitting there doing nothing
`functionname()` means execute the function

You have written a function that passes along a function as a parameter (a callback). That callback function is then passed to `ajax` for it to call-back, when required.

You should never execute the callback when you call your method (e.g. `del()`).

You should always just pass the function (e.g. `del`). The `ajax` method will actually call the function you passed when it has completed.

### Other problems

I gather the following is the code that will not "work":

```
 del = function(data) {
     alert("executed");

     $(":checked").each(function() {
          $(this).parent("li").slideUp();
     });
     $('#myModal').modal('hide');

 };
 postdata("delete/", "POST", gl_obj, del);
```

Written as shown above, it will "work", **but only if the Ajax call succeeds**. You might want to add the following for testing purposes:

```
function postdata(url, type, data, succ, err)
{
    console.log(succ);  
    //alert(succ);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        success: succ,
        error: err
    });

    return false;
}

 del = function(data) {
     alert("executed");

     $(":checked").each(function() {
          $(this).parent("li").slideUp();
     });
     $('#myModal').modal('hide');

 };
 postdata("delete/", "POST", gl_obj, del, function(){alert('Oh crap!');});
```

### Update (again):

Based on the comments and trials of the above code, the `delete/` POST call to the server is failing.

Note: you do not need to return anything from your postdata method.

To see the error, change your code to:

```
function postdata(url, type, data, succ)
{
    console.log(succ);  
    //alert(succ);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        success: succ,
        error:  function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            alert(textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

 postdata("delete/", "POST", gl_obj, del);
```

Comment: now this will always give error"oh crap" as success will only be called(in this case) with arenthesis "del()"

Comment: 1) You should NEVER call it with `del()`. Just take that idea and throw it out the window. That is not your problem. 2) If it says "oh crap" then **your Ajax call is failing**.

Comment: but my code will not run i have to have a solution buddy

Comment: Running it incorrectly is not a solution. Your "delete/" methods **on the server** is obviously wrong/broken... I will add something so you can see the error...

Comment: but thats not the solution :(

Comment: I have added a new test for you that will alert any error for you. Please post the results of the test.

Comment: this error it is giving in alert ..pasrseerror SyntaxError unexpected token A

Comment: That is your clue as to what is wrong with your server `delete/` method. Try testing your server `delete/`' method using Fiddler2 (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) which will let you send test POSTs to it. Please create a new question as this one is answered. You have another separate problem now that needs to be fixed :)

Comment: yes something wrong from my side, accepting this as a answer